# Prevent flickering of shiny updateSelectizeInput with server = T

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny app with two kind of choices in selectizeInput, a long one and a short one. If users want to see only the short one, they can click a checkbox and choices change accordingly. Moreover, if users see the long choices, select one choice which is also in the short list and click the checkbox afterwards, the selected choice should remain selected. And the other way around. Up to here everything works in the following app, which is using `reactiveValues` and `updateSelectizeInput`:

```
library("shiny")

choicesONE <- c("a","b","c","d","e")

choicesTWO <- c("a","c","e")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectizeInput(inputId="topic",
                     label = ("Topic"),
                     choices=NULL,
                     multiple = T,
                     options=list(maxItems = 1,
                                  placeholder="Please choose...")),

      checkboxInput("sub", "Show only subchoices", value = FALSE, width = NULL)

    ),

    mainPanel(

    )

  )

))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #------- Initialize the Memory ----------

  choice <- reactiveValues(selection = NULL) 

  #------ Whenever the inputs are changed, it only modifies the memory----

  observeEvent(input$topic,{

    choice$selection <- input$topic

  })

  #------ Update UI element using the values stored in memory ------

  observe({

    if(input$sub==T) {

      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           server = T,
                           'topic',
                           choices = choicesTWO,
                           selected = choice$selection)

    } else {

      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           server = T,
                           'topic',
                           choices = choicesONE,
                           selected = choice$selection)


    }


  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In my real app, the list of choices contains some thousand choices and without using `server = T` the app is slowed down enormously.

But if I set server to true, the selectize field is emptied after every click on the checkbox and then filled again, so that the selectize field flickers. This is quite unattractive and especially user-unfriendly.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the flickering and at the same time hold on to `server = T`?

Comment: Are you bound to this implementation using `updateSelectizeInput`? Otherwise you could use `renderUI` and reactively pass the choices to `selectizeInput`.

Comment: Given that my list of choices is quite big (~11,000) the inital rendering takes very long. This is why I decided to start with `choices = NULL` and fill them afterwards. I tried your suggestion in my real app and indeed, rendering of that very UI takes ages...

Comment: Sorry for my late answer... Keqiang Li's answer and kluu's answer both work in my MWE. Keqiang Li's answer is complicated to implement in my app structure though, so I accepted kluu's answer, but voted you both up. Hope that's okay. 
In the real app kluu's answer is unfortunately actually too hacky. In fact, there are no numbers, but words for selection and users can select up to 20 entries, so that the selection is sometimes displayed one below the other. However, the placeholder does not make a line break and a flickering occurs again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get something fully satisfying without going into `selectize.js`. It might be a little bit hacky, but if all you focus on is the UX, it can do the job:

```
choicesONE <- as.character(sample(1:1000000, size = 1000))
choicesTWO <- sample(choicesONE, size = 20)

...

observe({

    if (input$sub) {
        input_choices <- choicesTWO
    } else {
        input_choices <- choicesONE
    }

    input_placeholder <- isolate(input$topic)
    if (!(is.null(input_placeholder) || input_placeholder %in% choicesTWO)) {
        input_placeholder <- "Please choose..."
    }

    isolate(
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session,
            server = T,
            'topic',
            choices = input_choices,
            selected = choice$selection,
            options = list(placeholder=input_placeholder))
    )

})
```

To make it even more seemless, you could use a little bit of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `isolate` in your obsever

```r
observe({
  if(input$sub==T) {
    isolate(
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session,
        server = T,
        'topic',
        choices = choicesTWO,
        selected = choice$selection
      )
    )
  } else {
    isolate(
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session,
        server = T,
        'topic',
        choices = choicesONE,
        selected = choice$selection
      )
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since default you are showing the longer list of options, I assume it will not add too much burden to render both of the lists, considering the short list is much shorter.

The hack here is to render both of the lists but hide one of them based on the checkbox's value. This way, we will only need to call `renderUI` once to generate the DOM on the server side and we can pass in the choices already. (I borrowed the example from @kluu's answer, thanks!).

This way, we can update the selected option for the selectizeInput rather than updating the 'choices' param. And the reactiveVal selectedValue always has the correct selection.

```r
library("shiny")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("selectInput"),
      checkboxInput("sub", "Show only subchoices", value = FALSE, width = NULL),
      textOutput("debug")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )

))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  choicesONE <- as.character(sample(1:1000000, size = 1000))
  choicesTWO <- sample(choicesONE, size = 20)

  output$selectInput <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      conditionalPanel(
        "!input['sub']",
        selectizeInput(
          "longTopic",
          "Topic",
          choices = choicesONE,
          multiple = FALSE,
          options = list(placeholder = "Please choose...")
        )
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        "input['sub']",
        selectizeInput(
          "shortTopic",
          "Topic",
          choices = choicesTWO,
          multiple = FALSE,
          options = list(placeholder = "Please choose...")
        )
      )
    )
  })

  selectedValue <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  observe({
    if (input$sub) {
      selectedValue(input$shortTopic)
    } else {
      selectedValue(input$longTopic)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$sub, {
    id <- ifelse(input$sub, "shortTopic", "longTopic")
    updateSelectizeInput(session, id,  selected = selectedValue())
  })

  output$debug <- renderText({
    selectedValue()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```